# Split string after 3 times repeated <br>

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem, which I have tried to solve for 3 hours now.

I have a text like this:

```
<div>
Hello my name is Andreas
<br>
It very nice to meet you
<br><br>
Regards Andreas
<br>
<br>
<br> 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>       
</div>
```

I would then like to remove all the `<br>`, after they have occured 4 times in a row like this `<br><br><br><br>`.

I have tried split and replace, but can't twist it to work the desired way.
Hope someone can help:-)

Comment: Could you post the code that you used? Also: "Very nice to *meet* you" ;)

Comment: Unless he meant that he meated you with meat, like slammed the meat in your face. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this :

```
str = str.replace(/(<br>\s*){4,}/g,'<br><br><br>')
         .replace(/meat/g, 'meet');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/uhiyik/3/edit)